# Как задать ограничение ширине строки в textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня адаптивный textarea и меняет ширину в зависимости от ширины вьюпорта.
как я могу ограничить ширину строки в нем чтобы не появлялась горизонтальная полоса прокрутки и текст переносился без ограничение width ибо она выставлена как 100%?

Вот мой html:

```css
.contacts-cat__container-text {
  width: 87.70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.contacts-cat__text {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  padding: 13px 15px 13px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: none;
  text-transform: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  @extend %fonts-form;
}
```

```html
<div class="contacts-cat__container-text">
  <textarea class="input contacts-cat__text" name="comment" placeholder="Расскажите обо всех повадках кота"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, что вы хотите сделать. 4 раза перечитал, так и не понял какой конечный результат вы хотите увидеть.

Comment: @Crus смотрите, у меня адаптивный textarea и он растягивается как я и сказал в зависимости от ширина экрана и тд(задано width: 100%;), но текст внутри textarea не ограничен в ширину, тоесть когда textarea например 480px мне нужно чтобы текст внутри textarea тоже был ограничен в 480px и переносился, а у меня он идет без переносов и появляется гор. полоса прокрутки для просмотра текста

Comment: Все переносится ) http://joxi.ru/a2XZDkwIwvMv9r

Comment: @Crus у меня нет(  https://ibb.co/SnrRQQ6

Comment: Скорее всегог, у вас какие-то доп. стили на сайте висит на textarea. Например,     white-space: nowrap; какой-то, или что-то еще. По примеры что вы кинули выше - все отлично работает, нужно рыться глубже на сайте )

Comment: @Crus понял, спасибо большое, буду искать)